# Cannot get address (wcsstr) - undefined variable?

Tags: c++, function

I want to know all addresses of all standard functions. But only **wcsstr** is weird. I could not convert or push it as a parameter to log the address value. While :

```
void *address = printf; //OK
void *address = scanf; //OK
void *address = wcsstr; //Compling error!!!

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from '' to 'void *'
```

Its definition is weird. What is **' '** definition? Perhaps is it "**complex function definition???**"

Even the method :

```
printf("Address of wcsstr : 0x%X", wcsstr);
```

Also I caught the crazy compiling error :

```
error C2664: 'printf' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 
'unsigned short *(unsigned short *,const unsigned short *)' to '...'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you include `string.h` (or `cwchar` for C++)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Otherwise the compiler would show the error instead : `error C2065: 'wcsstr' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: It is illegal to convert a function pointer to an object pointer.

Comment: There are two one with const-params, one without. I don't think the ambiguity is solvable with either `void*` or `const void*`, and that assuming the types are compatible (which they aren't).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well clang on my Mac certainly doesn't enjoy it much =P

Comment: @WhozCraig is right. Here's GCC's complaint `error: overloaded function with no contextual type information`

Comment: But the `strstr` - similar definition it still works properly...

Comment: I don't think POSIX requires something from a C++ implementation. Could be wrong though...

Comment: ok. apart from the legality (void * to fn-ptr), if this is a road-block for you, I think you (unlike I, as clang is being most-stubborn, which is normally a good thing) can get through this by specifying which `wcsstr` to use. To do that will require an addition pointer and/or cast. willing to try it ?  **Edit:** actually, I take that back, you did down in Al's answer, no dice. I think your comp is as stringent as mine.

Comment: Oh, and use `%p` when printing your pointers unless your purposely avoiding it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the conversion being non-standard, you can use a `static_cast` to select the desired overload of the function.

E.g.

```
void *address = static_cast<wchar_t const* (*) ( const wchar_t*, const wchar_t* )>( wcsstr );
```

Or more clear (IMHO),

```
typedef wchar_t const* Foo( const wchar_t*, const wchar_t* );
void *address = static_cast<Foo*>( wcsstr );
```

Possibly add a `const` there, it’s nearly always a good idea… ;-)

Comment: clang still whines about it : "main.cpp:67:21: Address of overloaded function 'wcsstr' cannot be static_cast to type 'const void *'"

Comment: Weird variable? Sorry, now I've just tried your solution, but the compiler still gives : `error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from '' to 'const unsigned short *(__cdecl *)(const unsigned short *,const unsigned short *)'` - Could anyone explain the weird **'  '** definition?

Comment: yeah, still no joy with clang, which I kind of expected. bummer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I know! its starting make me scratch the scalp. =P

Comment: @xersi: it appears that you're using an old version of Visual C++, or possibly have weird project options (whatever). try compiling from the command line, add option `/Zc:wchar_t` to make `wchar_t` a built-in type instead of a `typedef`. The Holy Standard requires it to be a built-in type, while some  silly XML parser library requires it to be a `typedef`.

Comment: And if everything else fails, [this finally worked on clang](https://ideone.com/L4ThB2), which I expected it would. That error message is a real head-scratcher, though, to be sure.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf if you could, I'm genuinely curious. that link in my prior comment is 3 lines of code + the includes an main-wrapper. does it compile on your toolchain, because it does work on clang.

Comment: compiles fine with Visual C++ 11.0 (i.e. Visual C++ 2012)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The compiler works well with wcscpy, wcscat, wcsupr, wcslwr, but **wcsstr**??? - The unknown definition **'  '** I have never seen before, except its syntax appears when I try to call **printf**. The result still is the same. (Edit : Sorry, I am using VS2008)